# Why would my Cloud Run - to Firebase calls be taking so long?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to connect from the Java application running in Cloud Run to a Firebase database. There seems to be a lag of many minutes for my app's Firebase transaction to execute (and even then, I don't get the desired result).

The following method gets invoked as my app is launching:

```
    public void init() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init starting...");

        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                  new FileInputStream("/MyDatabase.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                  .setDatabaseUrl("https://mydatabase-222123.firebaseio.com")
                  .build();

        LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init 1");

        fbApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init 2");

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init 3");

        final DatabaseReference entityRef = dbRef.child("entities");

        LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init 4");

        Entity e = testEntity();

        entityRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
                LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init tx onComplete; com=" + committed + "; err=" + error);
            }

            @Override
            public Result doTransaction(MutableData data) {
                LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init tx start");
                MutableData childData = data.child(e.getGuid().toString());
                if (childData != null) {
                    LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init tx progress");
                    childData.setValue(e);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init tx null child");
                }
                LOGGER.info("FirebaseRepo-init tx will return");
                return Transaction.success(data);
            }
        });

        LOGGER.info("...FirebaseRepo-init ending");
    }
```

Checking the logs after deploying the app, we see:

```
2020-03-30T01:51:40.318532ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init starting...
2020-03-30T01:51:40.749160ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init 1
2020-03-30T01:51:40.781135ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init 2
2020-03-30T01:51:40.947959ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init 3
2020-03-30T01:51:40.949045ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init 4
2020-03-30T01:51:40.952295ZINFO: ...FirebaseRepo-init ending
2020-03-30T01:54:10.647748ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx start
2020-03-30T01:54:10.945862ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx progress
2020-03-30T01:54:12.546400ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx will return
2020-03-30T01:56:03.046096ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx start
2020-03-30T01:56:03.245789ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx progress
2020-03-30T01:56:03.547215ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx will return
2020-03-30T01:56:10.446070ZINFO: FirebaseRepo-init tx onComplete; com=true; err=null
```

The transaction is invoked about two and a half minutes after the app inits... and then again about five minutes later, and then finally completes. Moreover, when I go to my Firebase dashboard, I see nothing in my database; nothing has been added, even though I see no errors reported.

Any thoughts on the n00b mistake I'm making?

Comment: It is unclear what `movieRef` is ...and what you need the `final` keyword for.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it should be entityRef; fixed it. I'm not sure it needs to be `final`; I think I was working off of an example that has set the reference as final.

Comment: What are you doing to invoke this code?

Comment: It's a Vert.x application. Essentially, the main method of the app is called. Inside that code is something like this: `deployVerticle(EntityRepo.class.getName());` which creates an instance of the class containing the `init()` method above. The `init()` method is a lifecycle method that Vert.x automatically calls.

Comment: And what is `Entity`? Does it implement `Serializable` (if I remember that correctly)? Moving it's declaration into the scope of the transaction might help (in this case the `final` keyword might rather be meaningful, at least unless moving it into the scope)... because at first you declare a local variable and then you change the scope of execution.

Comment: It does not implement `Serializable` but I can make that change. I'll also rescope it to the transaction.

Comment: It still took awhile for the transaction to execute and complete, but this time about a minute, so it took less time. I wonder if it has to do with a warm-up period, since Firebase is a serverless platform. I'll explore that avenue more. I still unfortunately don't see the entity data in my Firebase dashboard.

Comment: Cloud Run isn't meant to run arbitrary code on deployment.  It's meant to run code in response to incoming HTTP requests as your run a web server on port 8080.  The delays you're seeing might be because of the way that the Cloud Run server instances are managed when no incoming requests are happening.  If you want to simply run some code on a remote server, Cloud Run isn't really the right product.

Comment: That's a fair point. What I'm running isn't the final product; rather, I was trying to "quickly" validate that my app was talking to Firebase at all, before moving on to wiring up the web controller. But that could be what's causing my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the comments in the question, it seems that Cloud Run is indeed working as expected, however, it might be the case that Cloud Run it's not the recommended product for this specific use case. As per Doug's answer `Cloud Run isn't meant to run arbitrary code on deployment. It's meant to run code in response to incoming HTTP requests as your run a web server on port 8080.`, which would make sense for the delay that is being faced. Might be worth it to check another product.